# Akka memory leak

Tags: java, scala, memory-leaks, akka

I'm trying to find memory leak in Akka application, and here is what I found in profiler:

[image]
Looks like Envelope and ConcurrentLinkedQueue classes are not garbage collected at all.

I found those Envelope objects content:
[image]

And here is the code, which I guess generated them:

```
for (ActorRef actor : actors) {
        publisherCancels.add(system.scheduler().schedule(FiniteDuration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                FiniteDuration.create(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), actor, "Run", system.dispatcher(), null));
}
```

Why those messages are not garbage collected? How can I fix that leak?

Comment: What does your actor do?

Comment: Your messages are piling up in some mailbox. I would say this mailbox is unbounded and messages are growing forever until the JVM runs out of memory.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have 5 actors (for loop interate through them), each of them receives this "Run" message to start working. This actors are basically polling MQ for new messages and then process them.

Comment: @hveiga Yes, looks like this. But why they are piling up? I know for sure that this mechanism works, but maybe 100ms interval is too fast for actor to perform http request to MQ?

Comment: It seems you are scheduling this "Run" messages every 100ms. Why don't you do it more event based and instead of scheduling every 100ms, just send a "Run" message whenever it was processing? In my opinion, your actors take more than 100ms to retrieve and process messages and there for "Run" messages are piling up in memory.